# Form of second-order expansion terms in classical linear response theory

Tags: statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry, variational-calculus, correlation-functions

I am studying the linear response theory from this [[1](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Time_Dependent_Quantum_Mechanics_and_Spectroscopy_(Tokmakoff)/11%3A_Linear_Response_Theory/11.01%3A_Classical_Linear_Response_Theory)] reference which basically tries to calculate how a system in equilibrium responds when a force is applied. I understand for the first-order we can write

$$\bar{\delta A(t)} = \int_{-\infty}^t dt_0 R(t, t_0)f(t_0).$$

$A$ here is some internal variable and we are interested in finding its new equilibrium value, and $f(t)$ is the force applied. However, intuitively, I do not see why the second-order should be written like this-

$$\bar{\delta A(t)^{(2)}} = \int_{-\infty}^t \int_{-\infty}^t dt_1 dt_2 R(t, t_1, t_2)f_1(t_1)f_2(t_2). $$

For instance, why is it not just the previous equation with $f(t_0)^2$? Why do we have to consider two forces here? This is probably a very basic question but I would appreciate it a lot if someone could help with a physical way of seeing this.

Comment: I think you should try to derive the second order correction by using the iterative approximation method. Just plug in your first order approximation into the equation defining the state (not sure if it has a special name).